# Get Android process context after interrupt

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I'm trying to implement some very basic Android process polling, i.e. I want to get a picture of what apps/processes were running over a period of time. I started going about this by using Android timer interrupts, so far so good. But of course, when the timer interrupt goes off, the current process is the kernel timer itself, not the user-space process that was interrupted.

So, is there a way to look at the Android context during the interrupt to see what process(es) were previously running/got interrupted? I've been looking at the Android kernel source, and so far the     cfs_rq field in     sched_fair.c looks promising.

Comment: I would check the data of the PCB however I'm no expert in that. Why do you want which processes you just interrupted? I see for that no real reason.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to get a sort of process "stack trace" to see what the process execution order was, and I'm looking for a light-weight solution that doesn't require connecting the phone to a laptop via usb _while_ the phone is being "profiled".